# Umbraco upgrade 8.1.2 to 8.6.1 Unresolved dependency

Tags: dependencies, umbraco, upgrade

I just upgraded Umbraco 8.1.2 to 8.6.1 and facing an issue by logging in on the front-end (members):

Unresolved dependency [Target Type: WebUI.Controllers.AccountController], [Parameter: calculationService(WebUI.Helpers.ICalculationService)], [Requested dependency: ServiceType: WebUI.Helpers.ICalculationService, ServiceName:]

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade deleted my Global.asax.cs, there where all the bindings... lol